# How can we "derivate" the P.M.F. (discret random variable) from the C.D.F?

Tags: probability-distributions

If we can find the C.D.F. by integrating the P.D.F. (or the other way around by derivating the C.D.F). How can we find the Probability Mass Function of a discret variable from the C.D.F.?

I know I'm able to find the C.D.F. from a probability function of a discret variable by finding the general term of the probability summation series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)) as SUM(p(x))=1, inside the range of the original PMF, lets say 2

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general $F_X(x)-F_X(x-)=P(X=x)$  $\cdots $ (1)for any random a variable $X$ with CDF $F_X$. So this formula gives pmf for any discrete random a variable $X$. [Here $F_X(x-)$ is defined as $\lim_{y\to x, y<x} F_X(y)$].

In the case of integer valued random variables there is a simpler formula: $P(X=n)=F_X(n)-F_X(n-1)$. A similar formula holds when ever $X$ takes values in a set with no limit points. If $X$ takes all rational values we have to use (1). There is no simpler formula in this case.

Comment: In that case, I will find the original f(x)=P(X=x) (let's say, a binomial or a poisson distribution) from CDF by looking for the limits and substracting?

Comment: @Limanido I have edited may answer.